# Preview what file is on the url from phone?

Tags: ios

I have saved a file from app and I have got the file's URL for that specific file as:

`file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3A85157B-6EBE-4265-B5AF-E3B190593212/Documents/Web2Pdf-google.pdf`

How can I see what file is presented on this URL? and how can I preview the file of this URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can't (*or rather **shouldn't** be able to*) unless you made the app as all iOS apps are sandboxed.